# Inkscape and uniconverter

Tags: ubuntu, python, inkscape

Started working in Inkscape and after drawing a few boxes I am being bombarded by a billion pop-ups with this warning:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/uniconvertor", line 13, in <module>
    uniconv_run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/__init__.py", line 83, in uniconv_run
    from app.io import load
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from conf.configurator import Configurator
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/conf/configurator.py", line 11, in <module>
    from app.events import connector
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from conf.configurator import Configurator
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uniconvertor/app/conf/configurator.py", line 13, in <module>
    from sk1libs.utils.fs import gethome
ImportError: No module named sk1libs.utils.fs
```

So I know I need to install the uniconverter, but I can't even get past the first package:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-sk1libs:
 python-sk1libs depends on liblcms1; however:
  Package liblcms1 is not installed.
```

`liblcms1` doesn't exist for ubuntu 16.04 as far as I can tell and some have suggested that `liblcms2-dev` is an alternative, but having installed it, I still get the same error above. Would love a solution to this.

Comment: Just as an info: I use Inkscape on 16.04.3 and don't have uniconverter, liblcms1 or sk1libs.utils.fs at all and draw rectangles without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are saving as an svg file?

If you intend to save as a wmf or other format, then you need to fix the uniconverter. BUT! you don't need this extension to work with Inkscape, just make sure to save and load all your files in SVG only and it should never need to call the uniconverter extensions.

Comment: I have placed objects from other formats onto my canvas, so I think when I try to save, inkscape tries to convert all of these.